# Grouping folders by name automatically in google drive?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-drive-api

I have a form on my website where submissions are sent to Google Drive and a file created according to `ClientName`, each submission creates a new file, but what I would like to do is group them by `ClientName` parameter within Drive automatically.

I have found online how to group but you must first know the `ClientName` of the file in which to group, is there no way to automate this in script so that new files are automatically grouped as and when they come into drive?

Any help/guidance would be much appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

For this you can

1. Create a folder with `ClientName` under DriveApp .
2. Before adding the file to your drive search for that particular
   folder using [searchFolders(params)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet#getCharts())
3. Add the file to the particular folder. That way all the files are
   grouped by the `ClientName`.

Hope that helps!

Comment: thank you @KRR, but I did want to automate the process as future client names are unknown thus it is possible to drag and drop when they are new but this would not be automated. Thank anyway.